# Efficient way of computing $A^{-1}B$ knowing $A$ and $BA$

Tags: matrices, computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two invertible matrices $n \times n$ matrices, for some positive integer $n$. Knowing the matrices $A$ and $BA$ (that is, specifically knowing their entries), how can we efficiently compute $A^{-1}B$?

Here, by efficiently, I mean using an efficient algorithm (so computing the inverse of $A$ does not seems like a good idea).

I thought about finding a relation between $A,BA$ and $A^{-1}B$, but I have not succeeded (a relation such at $A^{-1}B = CA + DBA$ for some matrices $C$ and $D$ that we can easily find out).

Another idea is to use the $QR-$decomposition of the matrices $A$ and $B$, because we can easily find the inverse of an orthogonal matrix and the inverse of an upper triangular matrix, but we don't specifically know the matrix $B$, and the complexity is $O(n^3)$, which doesn't seem like the most efficient way.

Comment: Do you have some reason or context that suggests that this might be possible?

Comment: In the case $B=I$, you are trying to compute $A^{-1}$ knowing $A$ and $A$.  So no method can be more efficient in general than computing an inverse.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

1. Row reduce $[A^t|(BA)^t]=[A^t|A^tB^t]$ to $[I|B^t]$, giving you $B$.
2. Row reduce $[A|B]$ to $[I|A^{-1}B]$

Does that count as efficient?

Comment: Doesn't this fall into the category of computing the inverse of $A$? I don't know the best computational complexity of matrix inversion, but I think that $QR-$decomposition is faster, right?

Comment: Row reduction on a square matrix is $O(n^3)$ with a leading coefficient of $\frac{2}{3}$, and so is $QR$-decomposition. So it feels like six and one-half dozen. Except to me, this row reduction approach seems more straightforward.